# How to have multiple traits of same base trait implement the same method

Tags: scala, traits, diamond-problem

I have a scenario with multiple traits inheriting from a fixed base trait. The base trait has an abstract method that each needs to implement. The class using these traits also needs to implement this method:

```
trait A {
    def f: Any
}

trait B1 extends A {
    val i: Int
    override def f: Any = println("B1: " + i)        
}

trait B2 extends A {
    val j: Int
    override def f: Any = println("B2: " + j)
}

class C extends A with B1 with B2 {
    val i = 1
    val j = 2

    override def f: Any = {
        super.f
        println("C::f")
    }
}
```

Then when I do a

```
new C().f
```

It only outputs "B1: 1" and not "B2: 2"

Is there a way I can define B1, B2 and C so that all implementations of f can be called?

Comment: The `override` keyword is not necessary in `B1` or `B2` as you are not overriding any implementation of `f`.

Comment: Also, it outputs `B2: 2` not `B1: 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well as you know which two diamond traits you mix in, you can call both *super* implementations and specify the trait from which you want to call each *super* implementation.

So, you could implement `C` like this:

```
class C extends A with B1 with B2 {
  val i = 1
  val j = 2

  override def f: Any = {
    super[B1].f
    super[B2].f
    println("C::f")
  }
}
```

And would get the output:

```
B1: 1
B2: 2
C::f
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of the [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#Mitigation) which Scala addresses by the process of *linearisation*:

> Scala resolves
>   method names using a right-first depth-first search of extended
>   'traits', before eliminating all but the last occurrence of each
>   module in the resulting list. So, the resolution order is: [D, C, A,
>   B, A], which reduces down to [D, C, B, A].

so the output should be in your case

```
B2: 2
C::f
```

so it seems it is not possible to call all the `f` overrides in both `B1` and `B2`, instead only `B2.f` is resolved.