# Disambiguate constructor parameter with same name as class field of superclass

Tags: scala

When playing around with Scala I had a code like this:

```
class Superclass(var i : Int){}

class Subclass(i : Int) extends Superclass(0) {
   print(i)
}
```

I found out that `print(i)` prints the constructor parameter `i` of `Subclass(i : Int)`

Now, my question is: in a situation like this, how do I access the field `i` of `Superclass`?

Comment: You can use `this.i`, I think. If you have any references to a constructor parameter, it gets turned into a field or something like that (even though you can't access it outside).

Comment: @user doesn't work :/. this.i also returns the constructor paramter

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that. Relevant discussion on the old scala website: https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/968

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/hjg7cg/bug_with_inheritance_and_default_constructor/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**@MarioGalic** answered this question. I'll just make some additions that are too long for comments.

Common misunderstanding is that `i` in

```
class MyClass(i : Int)
```

is just a constructor parameter and not a field. Actually if we do

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
println(reify{
  class MyClass(i : Int)
}.tree)
```

we'll see (Scala 2.13.2)

```
{
  class MyClass extends AnyRef {
    <paramaccessor> private[this] val i: Int = _;
    def <init>(i: Int) = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  };
  ()
}
```

So a parameter of primary constructor without `val`/`var` generates `private[this]` field. So

```
class MyClass(i : Int)
```

is similar to

```
class MyClass(private[this] val i : Int)
```

and NOT similar to Java's

```
public class MyClass { 
  public MyClass(int i) {
  }
}
```

without fields.

We can check that `i` is a field referring to it with `this` inside class body

```
class MyClass(i : Int) {
  println(this.i)
}
new MyClass(1) // prints 1
```

The field `i` is `private[this]` so we can't refer it outside the class body (or inside the body on instance different than `this`)

```
class MyClass(i : Int) {
  //println(new MyClass(2).i) //doesn't compile
}
//new MyClass(1).i //doesn't compile
```

I didn't find proper place in Scala specification but such behavior is well-known for a long time. For example in "Scala for the impatient" by Cay S. Horstmann it's written (edition 2, section 5.7):

> Construction parameters can also be regular method parameters, without `val` or `var`. How these parameters are processed depends on their usage inside the class.
>
> - If a parameter without `val` or `var` is used inside at least one method, it becomes a field. For example,
>
>   ```
>    class Person(name: String, age: Int) {  
>      def description = name + " is " + age + " years old"
>    }
>   ```
>
>   declares and initializes immutable fields `name` and `age` that are object-private. Such  a  field  is  the  equivalent  of  a  `private[this] val` field  (see  Section 5.4,“Object-Private Fields,” on page 56).
> - Otherwise, the parameter is not saved as a field. It’s just a regular parameter that can be accessed in the code of the primary constructor. (Strictly speaking, this is an implementation-specific optimization.)

Actually in 2.13.2 I can't confirm the second case.

---

Now let's have two classes.

Scala doesn't allow

```
class Superclass {
  val i: Int = 1
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
  //val i: Int = 2 //doesn't compile
}
```

unless we add `override`

```
class Superclass {
  val i: Int = 1
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
  override val i: Int = 2
}
```

But if `Superclass`'s field is `private[this]` everything is ok without `override`

```
class Superclass {
  private[this] val i: Int = 1
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
  val i: Int = 2
}
```

Actually if we try to add `override` this will not compile.

The reason is this being not overriding. One of fields is `private[this]` i.e. not accessible outside the object where the field is defined in, so these are just two different fields:

```
class Superclass {
  private[this] val i: Int = 1
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
  val i: Int = 2

  println(this.i) // or just println(i)
// println((this: Superclass).i) //doesn't compile
}

new Subclass
//2
```

or

```
class Superclass {
  val i: Int = 1
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
  private[this] val i: Int = 2

  println(this.i) // or just println(i)
  println((this: Superclass).i)
}

new Subclass
//2
//1
```

---

So in our case

```
class Superclass(var i : Int)

class Subclass(i : Int) extends Superclass(0)
```

are like

```
class Superclass extends AnyRef {
  var i: Int = _
  def this(_i: Int) = {
    super() //pseudocode
    i = _i
  }
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
  private[this] val i: Int = _ //pseudocode
  def this(_i: Int) = {
    super(0) //pseudocode
    i = _i  //pseudocode because "i" is a val -- well, compiler can do things that we can't do in source code
  }
}
```

Inside `Subclass` `this.i` or just `i` refers to `Subclass`'s field `private[this] val i: Int` and `(this: Superclass).i` refers to `Superclass`'s field `var i: Int`.

---

[Do scala constructor parameters default to private val?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694712/do-scala-constructor-parameters-default-to-private-val)

[Scala Constructor Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623687/scala-constructor-parameters)

https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/8384.html

Answer (score 6):

[Type ascription](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#ascription) can up-cast the type of `this` which effectively disambiguates the two identifiers

```
class Subclass(i : Int) extends Superclass(0) {
  print((this: Superclass).i)
  print(i)
}
```

---

As a side-note, there also exists the following [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57241754/5205022) that could be used in the case of method members (and which perhaps is not well-known)

```
super[ClassQualifier]
```

For example, consider the following

```
trait A {
  def f = "A"
}

trait B extends A {
  override def f = "B"
}

class C extends A with B {
  println(super[A].f)
  println(super[B].f)
  println(f)
  
  override def f = "C"
}

new C
// A
// B
// C
```

Comment: `this[ClassQualifier]` is illegal.