# Get the property of parent class in case classes

Tags: scala, class, inheritance, field, access-modifiers

If I have a case class that inherits another class like this

```
  class Person(name: String) {

  }

case class Male() extends Person("Jack") {
  def f = super.name // Doesn't work 

}
```

How to get the name property from Male class ?

Answer (score 5):

```
class Person(name: String) {
```

In this declaration, `name` is not a field of the class, it is just a constructor parameter. So it is accessible inside the constructor, but not outside (including in a subclass). You can make it a field by making it a `val`:

```
class Person(val name: String) {
```

Confusingly, constructor parameters for a `case class` **are** also fields even without `val`

Comment: This is standard misundestanding that `name` is not a field. It's `private[this]` field. If it weren't a field you couldn't access it with `this` inside `Person`: `class Person(name: String) { this.name }`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin If you follow the link in that post you will see this: "That's all true, but it should be treated as an implementation technique. That's why the spec is silent about it."
In other words, the specification does not say that it is a field.

Comment: Right, this behavior is not specified, but currently it is a field, otherwise you couldn't access it with `this`.

Comment: It's my post, I followed the link :)

Comment: But since it is not a field in the specification, the fact that you can access it via `this` is an implementation detail of the current compiler and should not be relied on. I also think it is conceptually easier to think of it as a parameter rather than a field.

Comment: Right, you shouldn't rely on this, but it is a field in current implementation :)

Comment: Right, but I was talking about the language, not the implementation :)

Comment: By the way, next implementation is the same https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BT1GBOASTSOJP22HNIy88A  (0.27.0-RC1)

Comment: And you write "`name` is not a field of the class" in your answer. It being not a field is also not specified :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to make `name` a `val` (or at least `protected val`) in `Person`, then it will be accessible in `Male`

```
class Person(val name: String)

case class Male() extends Person("Jack") {
  def f = name
}
```

When you wrote `class Person(name: String)` you actually created `class Person(private[this] val name: String)` so `name` was not accessible in `Male`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62686327/5249621