# private[this] Vs giving parameters without val/var in scala

Tags: scala, this, field, access-modifiers, modifier

I understand that marking a val/var as private[this] inside a class and providing a class parameter without val/var is same.

```
 class ABC (x:Int){..}

 class ABC {
   private[this] x:Int = 100
 }
```

In both the cases, x can be accessed by only the constructors and the methods of the same object. Is my understanding correct ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

reify{
  class ABC(x: Int)
}.tree
```

and

```
reify {
  class ABC(private[this] val x: Int)
}.tree
```

produce

```
{
  class ABC extends AnyRef {
    <paramaccessor> private[this] val x: Int = _;
    def <init>(x: Int) = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  };
  ()
}
```

And

```
reify{
  class ABC {
    private[this] val x: Int = 100
  }
}.tree
```

produces

```
{
  class ABC extends AnyRef {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    private[this] val x: Int = 100
  };
  ()
}
```

So the answer to your question

> In both the cases, x can be accessed by only the constructors and the methods of the same object.

is positive.

You can check that `class ABC(x: Int)` does create a (`private[this]`) field verifying that you can access it with `this`

```
class ABC(x: Int) {
  this.x
}
```

But it's important to emphasize that Scala specification doesn't specify either that `x` in `class ABC(x: Int)` **is** a field or that it's **not** a field. This is just current behavior of Scalac and Dotty compilers.

[Get the property of parent class in case classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64175034/get-the-property-of-parent-class-in-case-classes/)

[Disambiguate constructor parameter with same name as class field of superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62682390/disambiguate-constructor-parameter-with-same-name-as-class-field-of-superclass/)

[Do scala constructor parameters default to private val?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694712/do-scala-constructor-parameters-default-to-private-val)

[Scala Constructor Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623687/scala-constructor-parameters)

> I understand that marking a val/var as private[this] inside a class and providing a class parameter without val/var is same.

Well, it's not the same because with `class ABC(x: Int)` you have a constructor accepting `Int`.